# Why does Ash do 'human' things when no-one's watching?

Tags: alien-franchise, alien-1979

Why does Ash quickly start doing a warm up exercise before going into his observation blister?

It’s not as if he suspects anyone is watching him and as he is

> an android

There doesn't seem to be any reason why he should do it.

Comment: He also blinks when he's facing away from people and breathes, despite not needing to do so.

Comment: My first thought was just caution - he can't be 100% sure no one's watching, so better to act human if he can. However, Ridley Scott apparently says on a DVD commentary that he was loosening his mechanical joints. Unfortunately, my only source on that is a Reddit thread with a similar question (https://www.reddit.com/r/LV426/comments/64ppvh/alien_why_is_ash_jogging_in_place_right_before/), so I don't want to call it an answer.

Comment: *His kind* in the Aliens franchise seem notably more squishy than similar entities in other franchises.  Or at least, they have a lot of fluid and smushy internal parts when they come open.  As such, it might not be so unreasonable to believe these motions (including blinking and breathing) are indeed necessary, despite his different physiology.  Necessary for different reasons, perhaps, but necessary nonetheless.

Comment: @Valorum I'll keep that in mind. Thanks.

Comment: Well, it seems you were watching him. So it's good he was cautious about it.

Comment: In case any security cameras on the ship are recording him?

Comment: Memory is a bit hazy but I seem to recall that on one of the commentaries by Ridley Scott he mentions that that sudden motion was something Ian Holm just threw in while filming the scene. Scott discusses it as a possible malfunction and an early clue that all is not as it seems with this character.

Comment: Androids can't definitively know when they're being watched.

Comment: This little detail was cunningly reused in the game [Alien:Isolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien:_Isolation).

Answer (score 15):

Same principle as why traffic lights originally continued to operate the same even when there's no traffic: it's easier and simpler to program them and leave it. The more you add qualifications on when the program should operate (or not) the more complicated the program can get and the greater possibility of the program not functioning the way it's supposed to.

In the case of an android intentionally being undercover as a human, and you've programmed it to flawlessly imitate a human, why would you bother having it *not* act like a human?

Answer (score 5):

Because it would be easier to program an android to simulate human behavior as much as possible all the time rather than only when they aren't sure they're being watched.